# JIRA Issue type drop down list is blank when trying creating an issue

Tags: jira

When I try creating an JIRA issue, my issue type list is blank. But it works just fine on another PC.

Is there any setting that I need to activate? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The issue type scheme for a JIRA project controls which issue types are available. ~Matt

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed background on the difference between the two machines here are the possible fixes that come to mind:

- Be sure that you are using the same user account with the same user priviliges
- Check that you are using the same browser with all dependencies installed (java)
- Consider re-indexing JIRA from the Administration Panel
- Check your schemes to insure you don't have non-applicable dupes

Hope this helps.